# Bitcode in WeixinActivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, wechat

My project added the WeixinActivity by pod from [here](https://github.com/iDay/WeixinActivity)

As I found that Weixin (wechat) should support bitcode from [reference](http://wiki.mob.com/ios9-%E5%AF%B9sharesdk%E7%9A%84%E5%BD%B1%E5%93%8D%EF%BC%88%E9%80%82%E9%85%8Dios-9%E5%BF%85%E8%AF%BB%EF%BC%89/).

But I still found the below error when I install it by pod

> /Pods/WeixinActivity/WeixinActivity/Resources/libWeChatSDK.a(AppCommunicate.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)

May I know how to compile the project with bitcode set Enable?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

- Open your project
- Select the pod
- Select Build Settings
- Search Bitcode
- In Enable Bitcode set it to NO

Here is the screenshot for your reference:

[image: Reference wechat]